# A question about the function pthread_join()'s returning values of C language

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads

I'm using pthread_join()to get returning value in C language,whose second argument is not NULL but a 2-level pointer. Because I want to get a matrix.

However every time I'm debugging to check the matrix after the threads returned,and the data inside of it is completely wrong, the thing is that the result in the block of the thread's function is right, which might means that the errors occurs during the process of the returning.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<pthread.h>
  #include<time.h>
  int cti(char* c)
  {
  
    const char* ptr = c;
    int priceNum = 0;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        priceNum *= 10;
        priceNum += *ptr - '0';
        ptr++;
    }
    return priceNum;
  }
  struct Mat
  {
    int a[2][10];
    int b[10][10];
    int c;
  };
  void* Mul(void* para)
  {
    struct Mat* p = (struct Mat*)para;
    static int t[10][10] = { 0 };
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                t[p->c + i][j] += (p->a[i][k]) * (p->b[k][j]);
    return (void*)t;
  }
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
    clock_t start, stop;
    start = clock();
    FILE* fpa, * fpb, * fpc;
    int count = 0, n = 0, i, j, k;
    char ch, c[3] = { 0 };
    fpa = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fpb = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fpc = fopen("t10.txt", "w");
    while (!feof(fpa))
    {
        ch = fgetc(fpa);
        if (ch == '#')
        {
            fseek(fpa, 15, SEEK_CUR);
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 2)break;
        if (ch == '\n')n++;
    }
    rewind(fpa);
    int** Ma = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Ma[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n;)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fpa);
            if (ch == '#')
            {
                fseek(fpa, 15, SEEK_CUR);
                ch = fgetc(fpa);
            }
  
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                c[count] = ch;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[count] = '\0';
                Ma[i][j] = cti(c);
                j++;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
  
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", Ma[i][j]);
            if (j == n - 1)printf("\n");
        }
    int** Mb = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Mb[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n;)
        {
            ch = fgetc(fpb);
            if (ch == '#')
            {
                fseek(fpb, 15, SEEK_CUR);
                ch = fgetc(fpb);
            }
  
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                c[count] = ch;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[count] = '\0';
                Mb[i][j] = cti(c);
                j++;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", Mb[i][j]);
            if (j == n - 1)printf("\n");
        }
    int** Mc = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Mc[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    pthread_t p[5];
    struct Mat m[5];
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        m[k].c = k * 2;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            m[k].a[0][j] = Ma[2 * k][j];
            m[k].a[1][j] = Ma[2 * k + 1][j];
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                m[k].b[i][j] = Mb[i][j];
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        pthread_create(&p[k], NULL, &Mul, &m[k]);
    }
    int r[n][n];
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        pthread_join(p[k], (void*)&r);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                Mc[i][j] = r[i][j];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            //printf("\t%d",mat[i][j]);
            if (j == 0)fprintf(fpc, "#This is Row %d:\n", i);
            fprintf(fpc, "%d\n", Mc[i][j]);
            //if(j==N-1)fprintf(fpa,"\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(fpa);
    fclose(fpb);
    fclose(fpc);
    stop = clock();
    double duration = ((double)(stop - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time used = %.2lf\n", duration);
    return 0;
  }
```

[from24-34 is the thread function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICO21.png)
[from146-152 is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfBGs.png)

Comment: 'static int t[10][10] = { 0 };' .....think about that...why 'static'?

Comment: It mean, you are already signaling in a Mat struct, per thread: (structMat* p = (struct Mat*)para;', so, if you need some workspace for a return value, why not include it as data element of Mat?

Comment: Note: `Ma[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);` may be allocating the wrong amount of space, because you need space for `n` integers, but you are allocating enough for `n` pointers.  That's probably not too little space, but it may be twice as much as you need or more.  Similar for `Mb` and `Mc`.

Comment: This code is begging for a function to allocate arrays, thereby to remove that unneeded duplication, and another for reading an array from a file, thereby to remove *that* unneeded duplication.